# Why can my oscilloscope measure all frequencies equally well?

Tags: oscilloscope

I've got an oscilloscope that, according to the manual, looks like this (for AC):

```
---Cac--+-----+--------
        |     |
Uin     Cin   Rin      Udisp
        |     |
--------+-----+--------
```

`Uin` is the voltage input, `Udisp` is the voltage shown by the oscilloscope, `Rin` is the internal resistance and `Cac` and `Cin` are internal capacitances. I'm trying to find `|Udisp/Uin|` for different frequencies. So I rewrote this as follows with complex impedances:

```
Uin---1/(j*w*Cac)--+-------------- Udisp
                   |     
             Rin+1/(i*w*Cac)
                   |     
 0 ----------------+--------------

         <=>

Uin---1/(j*w*Cac)---Udisp-----Rin+1/(i*w*Cac)-----0

                             \_______Z1______/
     \______________Z2_______________________/
```

Using Ohm's law, since the currents over both impedances must be the same, I get:

```
Udisp / Uin = Z1 / Z2
```

However, this means that the measured amplitude (`|Udisp/Uin|`) does not depend on the frequency! I must have made a mistake somewhere, as the oscilloscope obviously can't handle all frequencies equally well. Where is the mistake?

Comment: I just saw that I added Cin and Rin as if they were in series, sorry! But I get the same problem if I do it correctly, namely that the magnitude of Udisp/Uin does not depend on the frequency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can see two problems here. Firstly, your analysis *does* depend on frequency. Replacing \$j\omega\$ with 's' for convenience, Z1 is given by :-

\$Z_1 = \frac{R_{IN}}{1+\mathrm sR_{IN}C_{IN}}\$

... from which the transfer function Z1/Z2 can be derived as :-

\$\frac{\mathrm sR_{IN}C_{AC}}{\mathrm sR_{IN}(C_{IN}+C_{AC})+1}\$

This is a first-order high-pass function with a pole at a frequency \$\frac{1}{2\pi R_{IN}(C_{IN}+C_{AC})}\$ so your 'scope will display frequencies higher than this with no loss of amplitude ... *according to your model*.

The second issue is that your model is incomplete. You are assuming zero source impedance and not taking into account the characteristics of the vertical amplifier which will roll-off at some frequency.

Comment: Thank you. Don't know what I was thinking about that not depending on frequency though :)